Exception Filter Nestjs not working on my websocket gateway
I'm using the lib ws on nestjs to implement a websocket gateway and using a generic exception filter, but, the filter is not working, the exception never callback the filter.
this is my filter, located in ws-exception.filter.ts
import { Catch, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common'
import { BaseWsExceptionFilter, WsException } from '@nestjs/websockets'
import { WebSocket } from 'ws'

@Catch()
export class WebSocketExceptions extends BaseWsExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        console.log('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMEn')
        /*
        const ws = host.switchToWs().getClient<WebSocket>()
        ws.terminate()*/
        //super.catch(exception, host)
    }
}


this is my websocket gateway calling the exception, but without callback on the filter

import {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    OnGatewayConnection,                                                                                                                                                                                             
    OnGatewayDisconnect,                                                                                                                                                                                             
    WebSocketGateway,                                                                                                                                                                                                
    WsException,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
} from '@nestjs/websockets'                                                                                                                                                                                          
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http'                                                                                                                                                                               
import { WebSocket } from 'ws'                                                                                                                                                                                       
import { UseFilters } from '@nestjs/common'                                                                                                                                                                          
import { WebSocketExceptions } from '../ws-exception.filter'                                                                                                                                                         
import { verify } from 'jsonwebtoken'                                                                                                                                                                                
import { config } from 'src/config'                                                                                                                                                                                  

    //extends wsg
@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/ws/operator' })
@UseFilters(new WebSocketExceptions())
export class WsOperatorServiceGateway
    implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
    handleConnection(client: WebSocket, req: any) {
        console.log('connecting')
        this.auth(req)
    }

    handleDisconnect(client: any) {
        console.log('disconnectign')
    }

    private auth(req: IncomingMessage): any {
        const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(req)

        if (!token)
            throw new WsException('No Token')
         

        return verify(token, config.serviceSecret)

    }

    private extractTokenFromHeader(req: IncomingMessage): string | undefined {
        const [type, token] = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? []
        return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined
    }
}


Sorry if my question is stupid, I started a short time ago in nestjs
I hope to be able to call the filter if the exception is sent

actually you can use exc filter with individual event handler decorated with
SubscribeMessage
but you can't catch any error in handle connect
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/336

It seems like you're trying to use a WebSocket exception filter in a similar manner as you would with HTTP exception filters. However, WebSocket exception filters in NestJS WebSockets don't quite work the same way.
The @UseFilters() decorator is not used directly on WebSocket gateways like it is with controllers. Instead, you need to apply the filter within the @WebSocketGateway() decorator using the exceptionFilters property.
Here's how you can correct your WsOperatorServiceGateway to use the WebSocketExceptions filter:


import {
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WsException,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { IncomingMessage } from 'http';
import { WebSocket } from 'ws';
import { verify } from 'jsonwebtoken';
import { config } from 'src/config';
import { WebSocketExceptions } from '../ws-exception.filter';

@WebSocketGateway({ path: '/ws/operator', exceptionFilters: new WebSocketExceptions() })
export class WsOperatorServiceGateway implements OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  handleConnection(client: WebSocket, req: any) {
    console.log('connecting');
    this.auth(req);
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: any) {
    console.log('disconnecting');
  }

  private auth(req: IncomingMessage): any {
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(req);

    if (!token) {
      throw new WsException('No Token');
    }

    return verify(token, config.serviceSecret);
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(req: IncomingMessage): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = req.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}



By specifying exceptionFilters: new WebSocketExceptions() within the @WebSocketGateway() decorator, you ensure that any exceptions thrown within the WebSocket gateway are caught by the WebSocketExceptions filter.

This is not working to me

@user24484638 Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately this looks likely to be a ChatGPT answer, which is commonly wrong. Hopefully someone will be able to provide a real answer to your question.
